# .NET Code Coverage Tool

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, code-coverage

I am looking for a .NET code coverage tool. I have tried free version of NCover but it is working only for one .NET solution whereas I have 26 Solutions and each solution having about 10-30 projects total is about 560 projects. I use a common directory for building all solutions. All these project belong to a single product which having hundreds of DLL files and 8 exe files. **I am unable to run any code coverage tool for all the 26 solutions at a time.**

Please suggest me any good Code Coverage Tool. I can also think about paid version if it is suitable for me.

Comment: I've used OpenCover with some success: https://github.com/sawilde/opencover

Comment: You might also want to look at either of these commercial products: [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) and [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/).

Comment: I have installed NCrunch but it is working for only one solution. But I need to generate a single report for multiple solutions. Please would you suggest me any other option.

Comment: I have also installed dotCover but it is working for only one solution. But I need to generate a single report for multiple solutions. Please would you suggest me any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to worry.

You can solve your purpose using free version of NCOver.

But for that you have to do some extra effort.

1. Generate Report for Each solution separately and save each report.
2. After completing Report generation from all solutions Open NCover Explorer.
3. Choose merge XML of more than one solutions and in this way you will be able to merge the report. Thus your combined reporrt for multiple solution is ready.